# How to create multiple submit buttons with different formats in a form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm working on a project in which I have a form which consists of a list of posts each with a checkbox and two submit buttons. One submit button is view, which takes the user to a template containing all the posts checked. The other is a delete button, which should keep the user on the page, delete the posts and refresh the list.

The problem is that I need to be able to change the submit format depending on which button the user pushes, HTML for view and js for delete.

Originally I had:

```
<%= form_tag multi_posts_path(format: :html) do %>
    #checkboxes
    <%= button_tag('View Checked', name: 'commit', value: 'view') %>
<% end %>
```

for just viewing, but obviously that wont work for deleting and I'm not sure how to change it to work.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a link_to to the deleting action, and then, give it the appearance of a button.